# Filter RSS feeds on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation

I'm looking for an app to read my rss feeds from my favourite websites but with a filtering feature by keywords. For example every article from a website that contains the word "pluto". On my mac I use RSS Bot to do so, but now that I have an iPad I don't know how can I do that again. Any help?

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend the newly updated [Net News Wire for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/netnewswire/id965347329?mt=8) (and [Mac if you choose the extra bonus](http://netnewswireapp.com/mac/) ability to have one unified feed synced across both OS).

- http://netnewswireapp.com
- http://netnewswireapp.com/ios/

The original author is a long time renowned developer and the current owners are equally respected in the community for doing top notch work.

Comment: yep, thanks, but there is no filtering feature in this app"

Comment: @hiru I use the search function to make excellent filters. I don't know if they will add smart folders or a more explicit filter, but I bet it's on the planning board if not something they have started coding for.

Comment: well, in this case, thanks, I'll surely keep an eye on it!

Comment: I would agree but the  app has been removed. I used it on Mac but  then t got removed. Nice  app but you can't rely on it being around.